# Access a table indexed by a table key in lua C++

Tags: c++, lua

Lua tables can have a table as a key, for instance:

```
a = {[{}]=true}
```

I'm wondering how I can index this from the lua C++ api.  For instance, I can do:

```
lua_getfield(L, -1, variablename);
```

To get a string key'd value of a table on the stack.  How would I put a table-valued key onto the stack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`lua_getfield`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_getfield) is nothing more than syntactic sugar around a series of commands you could do on your own:

```
lua_pushstring(L, variablename);
lua_gettable(L -1 - 1);  //The second minus one represents the fact that your table is actually one index below the top now.
```

You push the key onto the stack, then use `lua_gettable` to access it. This is true *regardless* of what kind of key it is.

The only question you have to answer is how to actually get that key in the first place. For that... you're on your own. Every Lua table has a different value from every other Lua table. And if your Lua script just jammed a freshly-created Lua table in the key like that, without handing a reference to the table to you or storing a reference globally, you're hosed.

Your only recourse then is to just [iterate through the table with `lua_next`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_next) and hope that a key who's type is "table" is the key you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks.  The way to do it is to recognize the table-key during lua_next, and store a reference using luaL_ref.  Then use lua_rawgeti(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, ref) and lua_gettable(L,-2).

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need to iterate the table with `lua_next`.
This link describes the process: http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_next.

Investigate the iterated tables and determine if its the one that you are searching for.